# Do plant and animal bacterial pathogen differ too much?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, pathology

I will be involved in a plant disease produced by a bacterial pathogen, Acidovorax citrulli. I've previously worked with animal pathogens such as Haemophilus parasuis. Are there any big differences among them?

H. parasuis and A. citrulli are 2 and 4 MB genome size. What are these 2 MB extra genome size for?

Comment: What kind of differences are you expecting? Related species can have unrelated hosts. It is not very uncommon. For example *Erwinia* is a plant pathogen that belongs to Enterobacteriaciae which also includes *Shigella*, *Salmonella* and *Escherichia*. There are several *Pseudomonas* species that infect plants.

Comment: @WYSIWYG. I'm not looking for a special type of difference, just asking for the most obvious ones. Maybe the differ at gene level, some kind of protein or transporter. Any paper studying all this would be also useful, thanks.

Comment: you really have to narrow down your question.